# Destroying a spammer account is not considered a recent activity

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

When a moderator destroys a spammer account, that is not considered a recent activity.

For example, in this screenshot, the last activity of a moderator is reported to be 8 hours ago, while that same moderator destroyed a spammer account right 3 minutes ago.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Destroying an account should be considered recent activity.

Comment: maybe the moderator went back in time to do, to preempt the spam?